# Can the producer-consumer prob. be solved using a single lock?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

I'm studying synchronization in operating systems and I'm a bit confused about the typical method (from what I've seen) of solving the (multiple) producer-consumer problem (with a bounded buffer). The only solution I've seen (as far as I remember) is the following (in pseudocode), where `N` is the buffer's capacity:

```
Semaphore<Integer> emptyCount = N, fullCount = 0;
Lock bufLock; // Starts unlocked

produce:
    emptyCount.down(); // If possible, decrement `emptyCount`; otherwise, block until possible
    bufLock.lock();    // Lock buffer before writing
    // *CRITICAL SECTION: write something to buffer*
    bufLock.unlock();  // Unlock buffer after writing
    fullCount.up();    // If possible, increment `fullCount`; otherwise, block until possible

consume:
    fullCount.down(); // If possible, decrement `fullCount`; otherwise, block until possible
    bufLock.lock();   // Lock buffer before reading
    // *CRITICAL SECTION: read something from buffer*
    bufLock.unlock(); // Unlock buffer after reading
    emptyCount.up();  // If possible, increment `emptyCount`; otherwise, block until possible
```

However, shouldn't a solution like the following, which only uses one lock (binary semaphore)?:

```
Lock bufLock; // Starts unlocked
Integer bufCrtSize = 0;

produce:
    bufLock.lock(); // Lock buffer before attempting to write

    // If buffer is full, unlock buffer and try again with next `produce` call
    if (bufCrtSize == N):
        bufLock.unlock();
        // *Yield current thread to scheduler*
        return;

    // *CRITICAL SECTION: write something to buffer*
    ++bufCrtSize;
    bufLock.unlock(); // Unlock buffer after writing

consume:
    bufLock.lock(); // Lock buffer before attempting to read

    // If buffer is empty, unlock buffer and try again with next `consume` call
    if (bufCrtSize == 0):
        bufLock.unlock();
        // *Yield current thread to scheduler*
        return;

    // *CRITICAL SECTION: read something from buffer*
    --bufCrtSize;
    bufLock.unlock(); // Unlock buffer after reading
```

If the latter solution works, is the reason it's not used (as far as I have seen) because it's slower? It shouldn't be able to cause any deadlocks since the lock is unlocked if the CS can't be executed, and it shouldn't cause a livelock since there's only one 'resource'.

There may be a similar question somewhere on here, but I didn't manage to find one; if one exists, feel free to just link it in the comments.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, if you are willing to waste CPU cycles and memory bandwidth on avoidable polling, sure.  Note that such an approach is spectacularly catastrophic on single-core and overloaded boxes, rather than just incredibly wasteful.

Comment: @MartinJames I see, so it's much more efficient to have producers/consumers waiting for free/full slots using semaphores than to simply yield, because it's more controlled (since the waiting processes/threads won't be unblocked until they are guaranteed to be able to write/read)? That would explain it.

Comment: It all depends..  if you can guarantee that the queue is mostly never full or empty, the semaphores may be seen as unnecesary system calls. That is not often the case, and so it's usually more efficient to have the producers or, more likely, the consumers, blocked, using no CPU or memory bandwidth, waiting for a free slot or for something to dequeue.

Comment: @MartinJames All right, thanks for the clarification!